# Leaving away the 目 suffix for ordinal numbers

Tags: counters, numbers, abbreviations

I've seen 「1ページ」 refer to "page 1" of e.g. a book. Wouldn't this technically mean "one page" and 「１ページ目」 be correct for "page 1"?

Is leaving away the 目 when referring to ordinal numbering of things a thing / common?

Comment: That's interesting. I don't think this would work in some contexts though. For example: "上から二冊目" would mean the "second volume from the top" while "上から二冊" would mean "two volumes from the top (of a stack)". Removing 目 here changes the meaning of the phrase. Maybe ページ is special because its used so often to refer to "which page" in a book?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nページ can mean **"N page(s)"** referring to the number of pages (eg 300ページの本 = a 300-page book). However, Nページ can also mean **"page N"**, the page marked with that number. On the other hand, Nページ目 means **"N-th page"**, and it's not necessarily the same as Nページ without 目.

For example, the following two expressions may refer to the same page:

- 第5章の2ページ目
  the second page in Chapter 5
- 第5章の256ページ
  page 256 in Chapter 5

[image]