# How do you say "n out of m" with 目?

Tags: counters, numbers

I'm writing an application which features pagination, and I would like to translate it into Japanese. I have the following English text:

> Page 2 / 115

Before adding pagination, I would have translated this as

> ２ページ目

But now that I'm adding it, I'm unsure. I can't find much on the "`n` out of `m`" construct, so I'm not sure if it's as widely used in Japanese as it is in English. From the one example I've found, it looks like, "A[counter]のうちB[counter]" is how it's done. How is this done with 目? Do I still need to include 目 to say "second page" instead of "two page?"

My best guess currently is

> １１５ページのうち２ページ目

Or I've also seen に, so maybe it's

> １１５ページに２ページ目

But this seems verbose. Is it okay to write something closer to the English one, like

> ２／１１５ページ目?

Alternatively, and honestly the question I would most like answered; how is this sort of thing usually done in Japanese applications (at least the ones that don't just have `[1]` `[2]` `[3]` buttons)?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/82422/5010

Comment: Whatever the maximum number of pages, the current page number will never change, so why specify page N out of M total in the first place?

Comment: @JansthcirlU If I understand what you're saying, depending on context, the total number of pages might be very important.  So, it would seem the OP wants to understand how to relay this information such as, "I'm holding page 4 out of 50".

Comment: @A.Ellett after seeing sundowner's answer I realised that there certainly are use cases for this question, I was in the mindset of referring to a page without thinking of the total number of pages. For example, if I told you I found a typo on page 8 of some document, it wouldn't matter if that document was 100 pages long or 1000 pages long, because the typo would still be on page 8.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your last question, it simply has something like 2 / 115.  The below is acrobat reader.

[image: page indicator]

In prose, you can refer to the second page out of 115 pages as

- １１５ページのうち２ページ目
- １１５ページ中の２ページ目
- ２ページ目（１１５ページ中）
- ２／１１５ページ目

the last may not be usual and look informal. It is possible that there are apps with these indications, but only likely for business applications.

===

If you are thinking about presenting query results, then it may be more conventional to give which records are being shown. Like (M 件のうち） N - N' 件を表示 meaning Record N - N' (out of M records).

[image: yahooauc]

Comment: I don't think １１５ページの２ページ目 sound natural... it sounds like page 2 of page 115, which makes no sense.

Comment: なんだかうまく英語で伝えられた気がしないので日本語でもう一回... 115ページ上に2ページ目があるような雰囲気がして変な感じです。袋綴じみたいな・・・？

Comment: @Skye-AT 確かに言われてみると変なので直しました。